# extracting unknown substring from a string in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have the following string:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=100
EXT:
LOCATION: string to be extracted followed by a \n
SERVER: FreeRTOS/6.0.5, UPnP/1.0, IpBridge/0.1
ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:basic:1
USN: uuid:2f402f80-da50-11e1-9b23-0017881892ca
```

I want to extract whatever follows `LOCATION:` until the new line.

I can't do `substring in string` method as whatever follows 'LOCATION: ` may change.

I tried making this string into a dictionary and then retrieve the value of 'LOCATION' key. But this seems like a waste of memory and processing time. As the dictionary is useless to me apart from that value. Also the dictionary may grow geatlt in size if the string is too large

Is there any other way to extract whatever follows 'LOCATION: ` until the '\n' ??

Comment: you can use regular expression for this task.  https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the whole string on newline. And then check each line if they start
with `LOCATION`. If it does print the remaining line.

```
string = """HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=100
EXT:
LOCATION: http://129.94.5.95:80/description.xml
SERVER: FreeRTOS/6.0.5, UPnP/1.0, IpBridge/0.1
ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:basic:1
USN: uuid:2f402f80-da50-11e1-9b23-0017881892ca"""



 for line in string.split('\n'):
     if line.startswith('LOCATION'):
         print(line[10:])
         break

Out: http://129.94.5.95:80/description.xml
```

Comment: Several reasons: *Zero* explanation for the code, shadowing the `str` builtin type in an example that people might copy and paste, hard-coding the value `10`, bad indentation. As it stands, @thefourtheye's solution is much better and solves the general case.

Answer (score 4):

You extract the string using regular expressions

```
>>> import re
>>> string = """HTTP/1.1 200 OK
... CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=100
... EXT:
... LOCATION: http://129.94.5.95:80/description.xml
... SERVER: FreeRTOS/6.0.5, UPnP/1.0, IpBridge/0.1
... ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:basic:1
... USN: uuid:2f402f80-da50-11e1-9b23-0017881892ca
... """
>>> regex = re.compile('LOCATION: (.*?)\n')
>>> m = regex.search(string)
>>> if m:
...     print m.group(1)
http://129.94.5.95:80/description.xml
```

Comment: is regex variable a string in this ?

Comment: No, but `regex.group(1)` is a string.

Comment: you probably want to split the search and group extraction up, so that you can test for `None` in case there is no match.

Comment: Yes, as @Adam said `regex.group(1)` is the string.

Comment: your answer saved my day, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can split the lines with `splitlines` and then split the individual lines based on `:`, to convert them to a dictionary, like this

```
d = dict(item.split(": ", 1) for item in data.splitlines() if ": " in item)
print d["LOCATION"]
# http://129.94.5.95:80/description.xml
```

To have the keys converted to lowercase letters, you can reconstruct the dictionary like this

```
d = dict(item.split(": ", 1) for item in data.splitlines() if ": " in item)
d = {key.lower():d[key] for key in d}
print d["location"]
```

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know how this post can be improved.

Comment: heck, I liked your solution so much I deleted my RE-based one.

Comment: Is it possible to lowercase the keys of this dictionary without affecting the values ?

Comment: @sukhvir Only the keys?

Answer (score 2):

string.index(character) is what you need :

```
 mystr="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nCACHE-CONTROL: max-age=100\nEXT:\nLOCATION: string to be extracted followed by a \nSERVER: FreeRTOS/6.0.5, UPnP/1.0, IpBridge/0.1\nST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:basic:1\nUSN: uuid:2f402f80-da50-11e1-9b23-0017881892ca"
search = "LOCATION"
start = mystr.index(search)+len(search)
stop = mystr.index("\n", start)
print mystr [ start : stop ]
```

Comment: read my update, sorry for misspelling my first answer.

Comment: This is incorrect. It yields the string ": string to be extracted followed by a ".

Comment: Adam : well, that's precisely what is in the string, read the question !